# How to use Select Tag Helper in view when data coming from a Service injected in Dependency Injection Container

Tags: dependency-injection, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I've seen and use the codes where the source is a ViewModel for a Select Tag Helper used in a view. But if the data is coming from a `service injected in a DI container` I've seen examples only of using old HTML helper for select tag. One such example is from this [ASP.NET 5 Docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/dependency-injection.html#populating-lookup-data) where author is using following to demonstrate the use of old Html Helper for Select Tag. `In the same ASP.NET 5 article example`, how can I convert the following `into a new Select Tag Helper`:

```
State: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State.Code,
           Options.ListStates().Select(s => 
                new SelectListItem() { Text = s.Name, Value = s.Code}))
```

**QUESTION**: In other words, if I were to use `<select asp-for="???" asp-items="@Model.???" >` using the same data source as in the MSDN Tutorial what would be my `asp-for` and `asp-items` attribute values would be?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like below:

`@{ var stateItems = Options.ListStates().Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s.Name, Value = s.Code}); }
<select asp-for="Model.State.Code" asp-items="stateItems" >`